# Visual Studio 2013 C# configuration settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I want to add include directories and libraries in my c# project like i can in my c++ project

C++ Project : There are options to include directories and linker dependencies.

[image]

C# Project

[image]

There does not appear to be an option in the project settings to add those settings. I added the path in reference path, but my debugger throws an error. Right now i've added all the dll in my project\bin\debug directory and its working, but i don't want to do it for all the projects. Where i can link these diretories ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You have to include references to code files and assemblies one by one.

The linker and compiler for .NET works different than you are used to with c++. That's why you can't just link an entire directory containing some code files / assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

you can add reference of library files which  you want to add into your project by right clicking the project under solution explorer and then "add reference" and then browse or select from the list of dlls..

Answer (score 1):

Add reference to your existing dll for every project which will be use it

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

https://www.google.it/search?q=add+reference+c%23&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=P-2fU472Bcr00gX-tYAw&ved=0CAoQ_AUoAw&biw=1920&bih=955